# multiple mosfets controlling individual circuits sharing one pull up res?

Tags: mosfet, pullup

i'd like to control several individual circuits using an array of MOSFETs and wondered if they have to have individual pull-up resistors or if they can share one connecting them to ground.

Or do the  controlled circuits interfere with each other if they do?

Thanks a lot!
Marcel

[image: schematic sketch]

Comment: You mean short all the gates together and then connect that via one resistor to gnd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small semantic issue: A resistor going to ground from a signal that is more than ground, is called a pull-down.

The bad news is: No, one resistor for all MOSFETS means all the gates get tied together and they all switch at the same time.

The good news is: An Arduino uses a microcontroller from Atmel. All their controllers drive high and low, so if your system never goes in reset you might not need the resistors.

If your system could go into reset the internal system of the controller will go floating, allowing some MOSFETS to slowly turn on, in this case, yes you WILL need all the resistors.